# Code::Blocks console black screen? no errors

Tags: c++, console

Look,i don't think there's anything wrong with my code,have all my anti-viruses off,this was a problem with avast,but now i've uninstalled it.Fast-forward to now, and i'm trying to figure out how do i do log files in console c++.So i found an answer and i did everything correctly,with NO ERRORS.

And boom,blank console..after a few seconds it says

" Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.087 s
Press any key to continue. "

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen( "output.txt", "w", stdout );
    freopen( "input.txt", "w", stdin );
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    string a = "null"; //defining string a and setting it to 'null'
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please help quickly,need for project.

Captain Oblivious said:
`So what's your question?` My question is **HOW** the hell do i fix this

UPDATE:
So i just messing around with this code,and i found out that if i remove

```
freopen( "output.txt", "w", stdout );
freopen( "input.txt", "w", stdin );
```

it prints

```
Hello World!
null
```

So i think there's something wrong with the     freopen commands

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Answer (score -1):

Try running the program by pressing Ctrl and F5

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Welp,this did nothing..didn't even run the program..Tried holding Ctrl and F5 **while** i ran the program,still nothing..

Answer (score -1):

I am a complete **idiot**. I don't know how i forgot to look at the project files,but guess what?
output.txt
&
input.txt
were waiting for me there.**sigh**

Comment: Also sorry to @Captain Obvlious & Energy for wasting their time